# Docker: Assertion error with Mono and PythonNet : Could not load runtime critical type Python.Runtime.Loader

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python.net

I am running a Python script within a Docker container where I use pythonnet to interact with .NET libraries. My Dockerfile uses python:3.9-slim as a base image, installs mono-complete and the necessary Python libraries including pythonnet. When running the container, I encounter an assertion error and a native crash.

Below are some relevant snippets from my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mono-complete ...
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org boto3 python-dateutil asammdf pytz pythonnet
...
CMD ["python", "./test3.py"]
```

And here's the error message I receive when running the Docker container:

```
* Assertion at class.c:3355, condition `is_ok (error)' not met,
function:mono_class_try_load_from_name, Could not load runtime critical type Python.Runtime.Loader,
due to Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.
...
Native stacktrace: ...
```

The error suggests that there's an issue with loading the netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0 assembly or one of its dependencies, which seems to be critical for the Python.Runtime.Loader. I've tried installing different versions of Mono and pythonnet, and making sure netstandard assembly is available, but I keep facing the same issue.

Questions:

What could be causing this assertion error and how can it be resolved?

Is there a compatibility issue between pythonnet, Mono, and the .NET assemblies I'm trying to load?

Are there specific versions of Mono and pythonnet that are known to work together without such issues?

Is there any additional configuration or installation step required for netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0 in a python:3.9-slim-based Docker container?

Can anyone please help?